# Is there a way to hide one item in a BottomTabNavigator?

Tags: react-native

I am building a project in react native. I want to use a bottom tab navigator, but the problem i have is that it automatically shows all screens in the navigator.
I want to hide one of the screens from the bar on the bottom.

Comment: Which version of react-navigation you're using? Also, can you provide your own code that you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on your screen that needs to be hidden

```js
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

<Tab.Navigator>
  ...
  <Tab.Screen
   name="screen2"
   component={screen2}
   options={{ tabBarButton: () => null }}
  />
  ...
</Tab.Navigator>
```